# Determinant and constant multiple.

Tags: determinant

For a determinant of a matrix to be zero, is it always necessary that atleast one row of a matrix should be a constant multiple of another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct. Look at
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Determinant is zero if and only if the rows are [linearly dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence). This means that one of the rows is [linear combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) of the remaining ones. The same is true for columns.

For various conditions equivalent to $\det(A)\ne0$ see: [Invertible matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).